# How to list custom audiences via Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I can create audiences using the Facebook graph API, but is there a way to list [audiences](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience) without knowing their ids?

```python
import json, requests
response = requests.get(
    f"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/search?access_token={FB_TOKEN}",  #&fields={fields}",
    params=f"ad_account_id={AD_ACCOUNT_ID}",
    timeout=30
)
print(response.text)
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

Only gets me this:

```
<Response [400]>
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#27) This method is only available to Workplace apps.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 27,
        "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to get the custom audiences associated with a specific ad account? Then go via the edge provided for that on the ad account node itself - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/customaudiences/

Comment: @misorude That + relevant part is the answer. Will you make it or shall i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [misorude's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009696/how-to-list-custom-audiences-via-facebook-api#comment116709397_66009696), this is the answer:

```python
import json, requests


fields = "id,name,description"

response = requests.get(
    f"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{AD_ACCOUNT_ID}/customaudiences?access_token={FB_TOKEN}&fields={fields}",
    timeout=30
)

print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

I also had to use `f"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/adaccounts?access_token={FB_TOKEN}&fields={fields}",` to get an `AD_ACCOUNT_ID` from the token to see that it should start with "act_" to avoid this error message:

```
<Response [400]>
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
    }
}
```